# Правильно ли выставлены модификаторы доступа?

Tags: java, ооп, инкапсуляция

Решил для себя написать небольшой пример без использования IDE и попробовать лучше понять темы:

1. инкапсуляция
2. наследование
3. абстракция
4. пакеты

   Структура каталогов:

   app\src\com\somedomain\TestApp.java

   app\src\com\somedomain\objects\animal.java

   app\src\com\somedomain\objects\bacteri.java

   Компилирую в байт код:

   javac -sourcepath ./src -d bin src/com/somedomain/TestApp.java

   Структура каталогов bin:

   app\bin\TestApp.class

   app\bin\com\somedomain\objects\animal.class

   app\bin\com\somedomain\objects\bacteri.class

   Запускаю: 
   java -classpath ./bin com.TestApp

TestApp.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.somedomain.objects.animal;
import com.somedomain.objects.bacteri;

public class TestApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      animal[] a = new animal[1000];
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      String[] name = new String[32];
      String[] sound = new String[32];
      int[] age = new int[32];
      char command_cmd=0;
      int count=0;


      for(int i=0; command_cmd != 'n'; i++) {
             System.out.println("name: ");
             name[i]=in.nextLine(); 
             System.out.println("sound: ");
             sound[i]=in.nextLine();
             System.out.println("age: ");

             if (in.hasNextInt()) 
                age[i]=in.nextInt();    
               else {
                  System.out.println("Please input the number! \nTry again!");
                  break;
               }

               System.out.println("Continue Y/N ?: ");  
               command_cmd=in.next().charAt(0);
               a[i] = new animal(name[i], sound[i], age[i]);
               System.out.println("\nBacteri was successfully added!\nName: " +a[i].GetName()+ " Sound: " +a[i].GetSound()+ " Age: " +a[i].GetAge()+ "\n");

               in.nextLine();             
      }
    }
}
```

animal.java

```
package com.somedomain.objects; 
import com.somedomain.objects.bacteri;

public class animal extends bacteri {
     protected String sound;

     public animal(String name, String sound, int age) {
          super(name, age);
          this.sound=sound;
      }

     public String GetSound() {
         return sound;
     }

     public void SetSound(String type) {
         this.sound=sound;
     }
 }
```

bacteri.java

```
package com.somedomain.objects; 

public abstract class bacteri {
      protected String name;
      protected int age;

      bacteri(String name, int age) {
          this.name=name;
          this.age=age;
      }

      public int GetAge() {
         return age;
      }

      public String GetName() {
          return name;
      }

      public void SetName(String name) {
          this.name=name;
      }

      public void SetAge(int age) {
          this.age=age;
      }
 }
```

Вопрос который меня волнует правильно ли я выставил модификаторы доступа для полей и методов? Если я не ошибаюсь privat поля и методы не наследуются, а точнее наследуются но недоступны, а protected не доступны за пределами пакета?
   С модификатором protected компилятор ругается:

```
error: GetSound() has protected access in animal 
System.out.println("\nBacteri was successfully added!\nName: " 
+a[i].GetName()+ " Sound: " +a[i].GetSound()+ " Age: " +a[i].GetAge()+ "\n");
```

по этой причине для методов всех классов пакета objects мною был выбран модификатор доступа public.

Comment: Вы написали в классе методы get и set для ваших атрибутов класса. Зачем вам они в protected. Делайте их тогда private.

Comment: Так как я ошибочно думал что private поля и методы класса не наследуются.

Comment: @user3686478 пожалуйста, изучите Java Code Conventions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/codeconventions-135099.html В частности, имена методов имеются с маленькой буквы. А еще есть ошибки (копипаст), например, в классе Animal, методе SetSound вы присваиваете переменную саму себе, игнорируя входной параметр type

Comment: Пожалуйста, не не вносите значительных изменений в вопрос после того, как на него даны ответы. Если какой-то из ответом вам помог - отметьте его как принятый (зеленая галка слева от вопроса). Если у вас возник новый вопрос, связанный с этим - пожалуйтса, оформите его в виде отдельного вопроса и дайте ссылку на этот, если считаете необходимым. Если хотите советов или ревью кода - поставьте на новый вопрос соответствующую метку.

Comment: @PashaPash  Извиняюсь, я хотел после нахождения и исправления ошибок оставить в этой ветке исправленный вариант своей программки.

Comment: Автор вопроса, я прикола не понял почему у вас животные наследуются от бактерий? Я конечно не биолог, но имхо бактерии это сорт животных, а не животные сорт бактерий, ибо если вы себя согласны причислить к бактериям, то я - нет. Посему рекомендую:
class bacteri extends animals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Все поля можно сделать `private`, а доступ к ним иметь через публичные геттеры и сеттеры.

Модификатор доступа `protected` означает, что поле или метод будет доступен в дочернем классе (даже если дочерний класс находится в другом пакете).

Отсутствие модификатора доступа — это package private, поля и методы не будут доступны из других пакетов.

Взгляните на табличку из документации: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

```
Модификатор | класс | пакет | подкласс | мир |
public      |   +   |   +   |    +     |  +  |
protected   |   +   |   +   |    +     |  -  |
отсутствует |   +   |   +   |    -     |  -  |
private     |   +   |   -   |    -     |  -  |
```

PS: в джаве принято именовать классы с заглавной буквы, а методы — с маленькой.